# container deamon is running but reported to be stopped

Tags: docker

The first problem is that, whenever I run the following docker command, I get an error regarding name conflict. Hoe can I resolve that?

```
mahmood@orca:cloudsuite_v3$ docker run -d -t --dns 127.0.0.1 -P --name master -h master.cloudsuite.com --volumes-from data data-analytics:master
WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns=127.0.0.1) may fail in containers.
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "master" is already in use by container 54a3b132af8c. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

The second question is that, when I use `docker exec` command, I receive an error which says  the container is not running. However, using `docker logs`, I see that the container is running

```
mahmood@orca:cloudsuite_v3$ docker exec -it master bash
Error response from daemon: Container master is not running
mahmood@orca:cloudsuite_v3$ docker logs 54a3b132af8c
start sshd...
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                             [ OK ]

start serf...
master.cloudsuite.com  172.17.0.2:7946  alive
root@master:/#
```

Why? Any idea on that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a stopped container named "master". Before running docker run  you have to execute the following command that essentially remove the stopped container:
    `docker rm -f master`

Comment: I tried that but got trapped into the `aufs` path which is an abnormal thing. Please see the output at http://pastebin.com/wESeYJNT

Comment: Provide the correct argument to docker log. Regarding the aufs path, which base Image are you using?

Comment: I tried everything from scratch (`docker rm -f` for containers and `docker rmi -f` for images). You can see the full output at http://pastebin.com/m4LqFRAY.